# YII2 problem with permissions and CAN function

Tags: permissions, yii2, roles, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

I have a YII2 advanced template application with a function:

```
public function isVisible()
    {
        if ($return = \Yii::$app->getUser()->can($this->getWidgetPermission())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This function is not behaving the expected way with a specific permission, if I add the following code to print all user permissions and the involved permission:

```
public function isVisible()
    {
        if ($return = \Yii::$app->getUser()->can($this->getWidgetPermission())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            pr($this->getWidgetPermission() ,'NON ALLOWED!');
            pr(\Yii::$app->authManager->getPermissionsByUser(\Yii::$app->getUser()->getId()));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I get the name of the permission with the first pr() and an array of permissions with the second pr(). 
What is odd: the array of permissions INCLUDES the first one.

For example:
output of first pr():

```
backend\modules\m3p2\widgets\icons\WidgetIconProjects
```

output of second pr():

```
[
..,
[name] => backend\modules\m3p2\widgets\icons\WidgetIconProjects
..,
]
```

So IN THEORY:

```
\Yii::$app->getUser()->can($this->getWidgetPermission()
```

should return TRUE, but it's not!
Am I missing something obvious here?

BTW: I flushed permissions and nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the problem was in the cache.
I don't know why but both:
**php yii cache/flush rbacCache** and 
**php yii cache/flush-all**
didn't clean the cache at all.
I had to manually delete the  Cache files (in my case inside /runtime/rbacCache/rb/)

Comment: Most probably permissions were the problem. But in that case, you should have gotten error, I guess.